# 'Must declare the scalar variable "@thisuser".'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this code and I have a problem that I can not solve. I want to access my SQL Server table under condition of the if but keeps telling me that I have to declare variable `@thisuser`. Can anyone please help me?

```
private void btnPersonalInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlcon.Open();

    string query = "SELECT score1, score2, score3 FROM tblLogin WHERE username = @thisuser";

    SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);

    SqlDataReader da = sda.ExecuteReader();

    if (thisuser == da.GetValue(1).ToString())
    { 
        while (da.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your Personal Info are:  sda.GetValue(3).ToString()");
        }
    }

    sqlcon.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is unclear for you from the error message? Your SQL expects a variable that you never define.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression, Syntax for user defined functions / stored procedures apply here. They don't.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add the parameter to your SqlCommand. You command does not know which value to fill in for "@thisuser".

You can add parameters like this:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("parameter_name", SqlDbType.TargetSqlType).Value = parameter_value;
```

So you code would look like this:

```
private void btnPersonalInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var username = "foo bar";

    sqlcon.Open();

    string query = "SELECT score1, score2, score3 FROM tblLogin WHERE username = @thisuser";

    SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);
    sda.Parameters.Add("@thisuser", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = username;

    SqlDataReader da = sda.ExecuteReader();

    if (thisuser == da.GetValue(1).ToString())
    { 
        while (da.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your Personal Info are:  sda.GetValue(3).ToString()");
        }
    }

    sqlcon.Close();
}
```

---

Thanks to Larnu for pointing out some problems with the AddWithValue-function. If you use the AddWithValue-function instead of the Add-function like above, the type-conversion is done automatically. This can lead to problems. For more information please check out the link in the comments.

Comment: variable thisuser is in c# code outside. I just want if the name of the user is equal to the username in the table of sql to give me the scores from it in a message box. And I am so stuck on this!

Comment: @GeorgeBeatle replace the `username` variable with your local `thisuser` and that should be it.

Comment: @GeorgeBeatle What do you mean with "is in c# code outside"? Is it a class-variable of the form? Then you can use this variable instead of the username variable which i declared in my example like fredrik said.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Larnu Good point! I have updated the answere.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to select from the SQL DB only the username with the value 'thisuser', you need to put the value between single quotes, because is the normal SQL string format.

Like this:

```
private void btnPersonalInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     sqlcon.Open(); 

     string query = "SELECT score1, score2, score3 FROM tblLogin WHERE username = 'thisuser'"; 

     SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon); 
     SqlDataReader da = sda.ExecuteReader(); 

     if (thisuser == da.GetValue(1).ToString()) 
     { 
         while (da.Read()) 
         {
              MessageBox.Show("Your Personal Info are: sda.GetValue(3).ToString()"); 
         } 
     } 

     sqlcon.Close();
}
```

If you need to select from the SQL DB only the username with a value which has been declared in the c# code, u need to write the query string like this

```
private void btnPersonalInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     string thisuser = "example";  // example value
     sqlcon.Open(); 

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thisuser)){
        string query = "SELECT score1,score2,score3 FROM tblLogin WHERE 
        username = '" + thisuser + "'"; 

        SqlCommand sda = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon); 
        SqlDataReader da = sda.ExecuteReader(); 

        if (thisuser == da.GetValue(1).ToString()) 
        { 
            while (da.Read()) 
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("Your Personal Info are: sda.GetValue(3).ToString()"); 
            } 
        } 
     }
     sqlcon.Close();
}
```

Comment: While essentialy correct, this approach is open to SQL Injection. He should define the variable instead.

Comment: In the second part of the code i shown how to solve this problematic, adding an example of thisuser as string with value "example".
Watching the code this seems to be a ButtonClick event and it needs probably to get the 'thisuser' value from some ComboBox or TextBox instead.

New Example: string thisuser = TextBox1.Text;

Comment: thank you very much. I have a variable declared in c# code, so I chose your second solution but now tells me the message System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '='.' That is near             SqlDataReader da = sda.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Even with the edit the solution is open to SQL Injection. If `thisuser` is `'; DROP DATABASE; SELECT '` it would drop all tables if `sqlcon` was opened with a database user that has that permission.

Comment: @GeorgeBeatle is the `sqlcon` declared into the class? if not you need to declare it into the ButtonClick event instead.

Comment: I have already declare the sqlcon. Still has the same message.

Comment: @GeorgeBeatle check the code, u need to write correctly the Select in SQL Code but into a String in C# code, so watch out about spaces syntax
`username = '" + thisuser + "'" //do copy paste from this`
And if u get the `thisuser` value from some kind of input, add a `isnotnull` check

Comment: They should add a parameter as shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58931974/73226 - not use string concatenation

Comment: @GeorgeBeatle I added a Fix into the second part of the code, to check if the given user `isnotnull`, u can do copypaste

Comment: @MartinSmith My query is correct thought, its a simple Select query, so u can give the username value as a string. The username value is already declared in the C#, so a parameter isnt required

Comment: Your answer contains the code `WHERE  username = '" + thisuser + "'"` - this is incorrect if the user name contains single quotes and is subject to SQL injection

Comment: @MartinSmith isn't it obvious? i mean u need to check it before calling a select from SQL. If the username contains single quotes u just change the Select `WHERE` code like this `WHERE username = " + thisuser`

Comment: That doesn't address the issue at all. If the user name is `O'Brien` or `Robert'); DROP TABLE students;`

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh ye, never seen this cases in my life (living in Italy), thats right

Answer (score -1):

You are using parameter at inline query but you are not passing your parameter

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: OK my bad .. will take care next time.